# hook into completed image upload filter

Tags: images, filters, uploads

I'm trying to run a little function to determine the luminance of an image and store that in the postmeta for that image..

I have the function working, but id like it to fire when an image has finished uploading.. does anyone know the function/filter/action i should hook into for this?

ive looked at

- image_attachment_fields_to_save
- attachment_fields_to_save
- wp_handle_upload
- media_upload_form_handler
- wp_generate_attachment_metadata

and i just cant seem to make any of them simply run an addition to the postmeta table for the image

currently my code looks something like:

```
function insert_luminance_data($post, $attachment) {
    if ( substr($post['post_mime_type'], 0, 5) == 'image' ) {
        $lum = 'TEST';
        add_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'image_lum', $lum, true ) || update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'image_lum', $lum );
    }
    return $post;
}

add_filter('image_attachment_fields_to_save', 'insert_luminance_data', 10, 2);
```

but this isnt working.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

---

**SOLUTION** Thanks to s_ha_dum

```
function get_avg_luminance($filename, $num_samples=10) {
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

    $width = imagesx($img);
    $height = imagesy($img);

    $x_step = intval($width/$num_samples);
    $y_step = intval($height/$num_samples);

    $total_lum = 0;

    $sample_no = 1;

    for ($x=0; $x<$width; $x+=$x_step) {
        for ($y=0; $y<$height; $y+=$y_step) {

            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

            // choose a simple luminance formula from here
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596216/formula-to-determine-brightness-of-rgb-color
            $lum = ($r+$r+$b+$g+$g+$g)/6;

            $total_lum += $lum;

            $sample_no++;
        }
    }

    // work out the average
    $avg_lum  = $total_lum/$sample_no;
    return $avg_lum;
    // assume a medium gray is the threshold, #acacac or RGB(172, 172, 172)
    // this equates to a luminance of 170
}

function insert_luminance_data($post_ID) {
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_ID, 'large' )[0];
    $lum = get_avg_luminance($src, 10, true);
    add_post_meta( $post_ID, 'image_lum', $lum, true ) || update_post_meta( $post_ID, 'image_lum', $lum );
    return $post_ID;
}

add_filter('add_attachment', 'insert_luminance_data', 10, 2);
```

this creates a number between 0 and 255 that represents the luminance of the image.. this is particularly useful if you are layering text over a background image and wish to know if the image is mostly light or mostly dark.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress' media handling strikes me as scattered and inconsistent. I say that only to say that I can't promise this will work in all cases. However, I think I'd use the [`add_attachment` hook from `wp_insert_attachment`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L3783).

You will get a post ID, so you will have to ...

1. retrieve the image src with [`wp_get_attachment_imge_src`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src),
   probably,
2. retrieve the image itself and process it (not sure how you intend to
   do that),
3. and save the extra data.

Comment: thanks so much, this helped heaps, i will update my question with the full solution to what i was trying to do :)

Comment: ok,wanted to ask will this run for every attachment if a post has an image gallery?

Comment: If you have written a solution, please post it in the "Answer" box, not as a edit to your question.